# Deleting a .zip file from a directory

Tags: php, delete-file

I am writing some code which allows a user to upload a .zip file. When they upload the file the .zip gets moved to its correct location on the server. That all works correctly.

I have created a button that allows a user to delete the file they have uploaded. When the button gets click, I am using ajax to call on a .php file that houses the `unlink();` code.

**The Ajax Call**

```
function delete_custom_pack() {

                var phpfilepath = '/path/to/php/file/';

                //console.log( phpfilepath );


                    jQuery.ajax({
                      method: 'get',
                      url: phpfilepath ,
                      success: function() {
                        alert("successfully got file");
                      },
                      error: function() {
                        alert("error getting file");            
                      }

                    });

            }
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php

$filename = 'http://www.some-site/wp-content/uploads/custom-folder/custom-pack/test.zip';

unlink($filename);

?>
```

I receive the alert "successfully got the file", but the file is never unlinked on the server. It still resides in the directory. The success call is just letting me know it successfully got the php file. The `unlink($file);` inside of my PHP file doesn't seem to be executed.

Comment: What do your logs say? You probably don't have permission.

Comment: The unlink cant use a URL, just a path

Comment: unlink returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Comment: In this case, I will `unlink("http://google.com")`

Comment: Imagine if that actually worked.. what would stop me from doing `unlink('http://google.com/robots.txt');`. @MoeTsao o/

Comment: @MikeB lol very good point. I hadn't even considered that. Thanks for the laugh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`unlink()` takes a path, not a URL.  You must give it the path on the server, for example `unlink('/var/www/mysite/files/upload.zip');`

See [unlink() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Comment: Interesting, let me give this a go and see what occurs

Comment: Please note that this is not entirely true: "As of PHP 5.0.0 unlink() can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a listing of which wrappers support unlink()." (from the php documentation)

Comment: Very interesting.  That explains why it didn't just error.  I wasn't aware of this change and am curious to see how it works in practice.

Comment: Still unable to get it working, even with a path. Very strange.

Comment: Make sure the path is correct.  Do some debugging using [file_exists()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and [is_writable()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) to test the file and the directory.  Ensure the user PHP runs as has permissions to the directory and the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
  foreach (glob("*.zip") as $filename) {
     if(unlink($filename))
            echo "success" ;
     else
            echo "Failure"
    }
```

glob(), returns an array containing matched files/directories.